# How to edit Content inside Collapsible Widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I am working in Jquery Mobile and have hit my next brick wall, which I am hoping somebody will kindly point out where I am going wrong.

I have a collapsible widget which within I wish to amend the content with different values.

An example of my HTML

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" id="solar_collapsible">
<h3>Solar Power Information</h3>
<p id="solar_current"></p>
</div>
```

I am trying to amend id "solar_current" below:

```
document.getElementById("#solar_current").innerHTML = "Solar Current = 13";
```

Currently I receive this error in Google Chrome :-

Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

I have stripped my code back but after searching all afternoon I can not find any reference or other questions relating directly to this problem.

Has Solar_current not been created yet ? is this the reason for the error ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried removing the "#" from getElementById? That's pretty exclusive to selector querying in jQuery

Comment: Thank you Steve, I spent last night on this as well, I had thought incorrectly because the element was within a collapsible widget it somehow was making it more complex. Yes you fixed it for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you are using jQuery anyway, why not use it:

```
$("#solar_current").html("Solar Current = 13");
```

You can run this in the pagecreate event of the page.

If you want to use plain javascript, just remove the "#" as Steve Hynding suggested.:

```
document.getElementById("solar_current").innerHTML = "Solar Current = 13";
```

Comment: Ezanker, Thank you for expanding upon it and showing me a better way to do it. I had written my own basic function to do this in another script but was using variables, when writing this one as I was just practicing I had copied and pasted the normal # into my code. I like the Jquery way you have put forward and will take that forward in to my code. Much appreciated. Andy.